# Excluding XML empty elements with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have following xml input file, and trying to get an output xml without empty nodes.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/04/secext">
    <soap:Body>
        <InstantIDResponseEx xmlns="http://webservices.seisint.com/WsIdentity">
            <response>
                <Header>
                    <Status>0</Status>
                    <TransId>41904</TransId>
                    <User></User>
                </Header>
                <Result>
                     <Data/>
                </Result>
            </response>
        </InstantIDResponseEx>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I am expecting the output is like following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <Verification_response>
     <System_Data>
          <STATUSMESSAGE>0</STATUSMESSAGE>
          <TRANSACTIONID>41904</TRANSACTIONID>
     </System_Data>
   </Verification_response>
```

Comment: What part of the problem are you having difficulty with? What did you try, and where did you get stuck?

Comment: My question is that how to transform the xml file to another xml file in which the empty nodes are excluded.

Comment: My question is that how to write an xslt stylesheet  to transform the xml file to another xml file in which the empty nodes are excluded.

Comment: Well, I'm not going to write the whole stylesheet for you. If you show us what you've achieved so far then we can see where you are having difficulty and help you over the next hurdle.

Comment: I have added a stylesheet. I am new to XSLT, so that I am trying to find the best way to exclude the empty elements from the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several things wrong with your stylesheet that explain why you're finding this difficult.

Firstly, it's completely monolithic: you've just got a single template rule matching the root node, and that makes adding conditional logic very messy. You should aim for the "recursive descent" pattern where each node is processed with a template rule that matches the node and calls apply-templates to process its children.

Secondly, the use of disable-output-escaping is just bizarre. I'm amazed how often I see this in beginners' stylesheets. In some cases it's done because people haven't understood that XSLT is about producing a node tree as the result, it's not about producing lexical XML. But in cases like this it's just unnecessary and wrong: if there are special characters in your text then you want them escaped, and disabling the escaping will just give you bad output when special characters appear in the data. Don't do it.

Now on to your problem.

First it's a good idea to add

```
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
```

for this kind of XML where the whitespace has no meaning and just gets in the way.

Now you can write rules for the Status and TransId elements:

```
<xsl:template match="Status">
  <STATUSMESSAGE>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </STATUSMESSAGE>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="TransId">
  <TRANSACTIONID>
   <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </TRANSACTIONID>
</xsl:template>
```

and the general rule for other elements seems to be:

```
<xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
```

though that's actually the default rule so you can leave it out if you want.

Now you're saying you want a rule that you don't want empty nodes. I'm having a little bit of difficulty interpreting that because you haven't given enough examples. But lets say you don't want to output the TRANSACTIONID element if the TransId is empty. Then you could achieve this by adding a higher-priority rule for empty elements:

```
<xsl:template match="*[not(child::node)]"/>
```

and then your top-level rule should be:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
   <Verification_response>
     <System_Data>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/Identity:InstantIDResponseEx/Identity:response"/>
     </System_Data>
   </Verification_response>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: The result I got is like:                                                    <Verification_response xmlns:Identity="http://webservices.seisint.com/WsIdentity"        xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">041904</Verification_response>
I posted the stylesheet in another posting. What's wrong?

Comment: You need to use the Identity: prefix in your match patterns.