# Remove the empty elements in XSLT transformed xml

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

This question is actually related to another [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43742628/excluding-xml-empty-elements-with-xslt/43767120?noredirect=1#comment74582381_43767120). I have a sample xml, an xslt stylesheet and a transformed XML output file below. The first thing I want to do is that I don't want the elements having no values to be generated in the output file. The second is that I want to remove those name space declarations from the first tag  in the result file. The result xml file should look like this

```
<Verification_response>
   <System_Data>
      <STATUSMESSAGE>0</STATUSMESSAGE>
      <TRANSACTIONID>41904</TRANSACTIONID>
   </System_Data>
</Verification_response>
```

XML input file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/04/secext">
    <soap:Body>
        <InstantIDResponseEx xmlns="http://webservices.seisint.com/WsIdentity">
            <response>
                <Header>
                    <Status>0</Status>
                    <TransId>41904</TransId>
                    <User></User>
                </Header>
            <Result>
                 <Data/>
            </Result>
        </response>
    </InstantIDResponseEx>
</soap:Body>
```

XSLT style sheet:

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
                xmlns:Identity="http://webservices.seisint.com/WsIdentity" 
                xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
                xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/04/secext" version="1.0">
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>


    <!-- ****** MAIN TEMPLATE ******* -->
    <xsl:template match="/">
       <Verification_response>   
              <xsl:apply-templates select="/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/Identity:InstantIDResponseEx/Identity:response"/>
       </Verification_response>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match = "Identity:response"> 
      <System_Data>
      <xsl:apply-templates select = "Identity:Header" /> 
      </System_Data>
      <Received>
      <xsl:apply-templates select = "Identity:Result" /> 
      </Received>
   </xsl:template>  

    <xsl:template match="Identity:Header">
      <STATUSMESSAGE>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Identity:Status"/>
      </STATUSMESSAGE>
      <TRANSACTIONID>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Identity:TransId"/>     
      </TRANSACTIONID>
      <Client>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Identity:User"/>
      </Client>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Identity:Result">
      <Content>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Identity:Data"/>
      </Content>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Identity:Status">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Identity:TransId">
       <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>     

    <xsl:template match="Identity:User">
       <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template> 

    <xsl:template match="Identity:Data">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Transformed XML:

```
    <Verification_response xmlns:Identity="http://webservices.seisint.com/WsIdentity"
                       xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
                       xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/04/secext">
   <System_Data>
      <STATUSMESSAGE>0</STATUSMESSAGE>
      <TRANSACTIONID>41904</TRANSACTIONID>
      <Client/>
   </System_Data>
   <Received>
      <Content/>
   </Received>
</Verification_response>
```

I tried to add following piece of code before the root node from another posting in the forum, but it was not working. Could anyone help me on this problem?

```
 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match=
  "*[not(node())]
  |
   *[not(node()[2])
   and
     node()/self::text()
   and
     not(normalize-space())
     ]
  "/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the namespace declarations, add the following attribute to your `xsl:stylesheet` element: `exclude-result-prefixes="Identity wsse soap"`.

To remove empty elements, you will need to modify your stylesheet structure. The problem here is that you're creating literal result element wrappers without checking if any content exists. So you need to either create them conditionally - for example, change:

```
<Received>
    <xsl:apply-templates select = "Identity:Result" /> 
</Received>
```

to:

```
<xsl:if test="Identity:Result//text()">
    <Received>
        <xsl:apply-templates select = "Identity:Result" /> 
    </Received>
</xsl:if>
```

or move the creation of the wrapper to the template matching `Identity:Result` and apply templates to it conditionally as:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select = "Identity:Result[.//text()]" />
```

---

Note that this interprets "empty" as having no descendant text nodes.